Wiring Alarm.com ADC T-2000 smart Thermostat from 24 volt DC adaptor
I just receive Alarm.com ADC T-2000 smart Thermostat.
Previously, our electric water heater was managed by a simple(non-smart) thermostat that was connected to a cable with 2 white wire. One on the RH and the other on W. There was no other wire.
Considering that, I was not able to install new wiring to our system. I bought a 24 volts adapter.
First I connected the new smart thermostat to the terminal RH and W as they were on the old thermostat. After I install the 24 volts adapter and connect as I was advised to RH and C. See picture.
My questions are : 1- Is the wiring of the new thermostat correct? 2-Is it normal to have 2 wire on the RH terminal? 3-Are there any better options?
Thank you

Does  it  work sir?

Yes it seem to work but I would prefer to have 1  wire by terminal.

This is a follow up to this question.   More details about the environment are there.
If you don't want the new adapter, and extra wires, at the thermostat you can put them at the boiler.   You have extra wires available.  So plug the adapter into an outlet nearby, connect one side to the blue wire from your thermostat that you should connect to C there, and connect the other side to the T terminal that is connected to Rh on your thermostat.
I noticed your boiler has available "24V" and "C" terminals!  MAYBE this can provide the same function.   I'm not sure that it's ok to short the 24V terminal to one of the T terminals. It's not documented.  You could ask the manufacturer.   It's ok to do that with a separate adapter but may cause problems if you use the internal one.   But it might work!  You would just connect the boiler's C to the thermostat's C, and  the boiler's 24V to one of the boiler's T terminals, the one that is connected to the thermostat's Rh.

BTW: Most thermostat / furnace wiring I've dealt with recently uses 24V  AC  not DC wiring.   Hopefully you just typed the title incorrectly.

Some (most? all?) are able to function on DC too.

Not a good thing to count on.  If you look at the linked question, the system clearly shows an 24 vac power supply in the furnace.

@DaveM right, not a good thing to count on for the furnace systems generally.  But for a modern electronic thermostat that accepts 24VAC, there is a very good chance it uses some diodes and a capacitor to condition the AC into stable DC, and an already-stable DC power source will pass through that just fine.  It's certainly worth a shot, if you happen to have a DC PSU.
